# RODBC sqlQuery vs sqlFetch

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

What is the difference bewteen the two RODBC functions: `sqlQuery` and `sqlFetch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send this command:

```
library(RODBC)
?sqlQuery
?sqlFetch
```

And from the guide:

> sqlQuery: Submit an SQL query to an ODBC database, and retrieve the
>   results.
>
> sqlFetch: Read some or all of a table from an ODBC database into a data
>   frame.

Comment: I did check the documentation, and to be honest, it seems that both functions do the same thing at face value. Is there an underlying difference in how they retrieve the results?

Comment: Look at details and example: `sqlQuery` needs a query and retrieves results via `sqlGetResult`. "`sqlFetch` by default retrieves the the entire contents of the table" .

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you!